# UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\ denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an application that writes the data in a pdf file. The pdf file exists in wwwRoot directory inside the application. This is how I am accessing the pdf file:

```
  string blankPDF = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "BlankPDFFiles");
    string filledPDF = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "FilledPDFFiles");
```

I am getting the blank PDF file from wwwRoot/ BlankPDFFiles and writing to the file and then saving the file to WWWRoot/FilledPDFFiles with a different name using this code:

```
 string pathToFile = filledPDF + "\\Package" + "_" + employee.EmployeeNumber + ".pdf";
 pdf.Save(pathToFile);
```

I am using third party tool to write to the pdf file. This is working fine on my local computer, but when I deployed the code to server. I start getting the error saying

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Package\wwwroot\FilledPDFFiles\test1234.pdf' is denied.
```

folder FilledPDF exists in wwwRoot so not sure why it is going to D:\inetpub\wwwroot\ rather than going directly to Package\wwwroot. This is my directory structure:

[image]

Comment: Do you have static file reference within your program.cs file? Hows it that? Could you include within the question? In addition, can you access it in local test? In IIS did you assigned `IIS_IUSRS` permission to that folder?

Comment: I also noticed your saving pdf file seems not correct. Please double check it.

Comment: Hi @Md Farid Uddin Kiron, As soon as I ran the application under IIS_IUSRS, it started working!

Comment: May I know reason for dowwn vote?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yeah you're breaking almost every security rule in the book opening up wwwroot for downloads. Consider this right, mark a controller method with [AllowAnonymous] and export the PDF that way.

Comment: But I just pointed on OPs concern. There was nothing shared about the controller and auth related snippet. How come I drag that issue here?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have deleted my answer, may I learn the correct asnwer from you?

Comment: For security the best would be to upload to AWS or Azure and use a Presigned Url or SharedAccessSignature and that would remove the security concerns, having a Controller method is perfectly fine, though when it comes to opening up directories on a web server in general that is BAD practice - particularly root folders where the appsettings and config are located.

Comment: Mine is an intranet application